# MYSQL matching added number query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Im doing MYSQL query.

Here's my table.[image]

I need a query that results a row that contains value in added counts.

For example, if i'm looking for value of 20,000 counts, result row should be 3rd row where date is '2016-09-03'((8576+8694+8689)>20000).

There is something wrong in my table schema, but help me querying.

Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't you at least be ordering by date?

Comment: Kindly share sample data and desired output in formatted text ( not images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for such a query, assuming date is unique:

```
select counter.*
from counter
inner join counter c2
on counter.date >= c2.date
and c2.searchword = 'cryptocurrentcy'
where counter.searchword = 'cryptocurrency'
group by counter.date
having sum(c2.count) > 20000
order by counter.date
limit 1
```